# How can I list the SSH connection sequence on a remote computer?

Tags: bash, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

Suppose I am working on `LocalA` (username `userA`). I use `ssh` to tunnel to `RemoteB` (username `userB`), then to `RemoteC` (username `userC`), then finally to `RemoteDestinationD` (username `userD`).

It would look something like the following:

```
userA@LocalA$ ssh userB@RemoteB
userB@RemoteB$ ssh userC@RemoteC
userC@RemoteC$ ssh userD@RemoteDestinationD
userD@RemoteDestinationD$
```

Suppose I forget which series of connections I used to connect from `LocalA` to `RemoteDestinationD`. It could have been one jump (e.g. `userA@LocalA$ ssh userD@RemoteDestinationD`) or three jumps (as in my example above). How could I programmatically determine what my series of jumps was? ("Scroll through your history, dummy!" doesn't count....)

I'd like a BASH script that would output something like the following:

```
userA@LocalA$ --> userB@RemoteB
userB@RemoteB$ --> userC@RemoteC
userC@RemoteC$ --> userD@RemoteDestinationD
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this, I suspect.  There are a bunch of true hacks you could do if you were willing, such as turning on X11 port forwarding and using different ports for counting.

Or, more obnoxiously:

```
sshcount=0
ssh userA@RemoteA "echo sshcount=$(($sshcount+1)) > .bashrc; bash"
```

And from there do something similar to get to B, so sshcount keeps incrementing.

Clearly this should be done via overwriting a `.sshcountrc` file or something, and source that from the `.bashrc`.  And then, you might need to make the file name dependent on some munging of `$SSH_TTY` if you want to support doing parallel versions of this.

And the whole thing is really a hack so maybe you shouldn't anyway and you should solve the problem another way.  Or remove the need for counting in the first place.